# AWS - Looping over each region

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I'm trying to loop into all aws region but i got this error message below :

any idea how to fix this ?

```
Get-EC2SecurityGroup : AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
At line:9 char:17
+ $EC2GroupList = Get-EC2SecurityGroup -Region $region | Select-Object  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...rityGroupCmdlet:GetEC2SecurityGroupCmdlet) [Get-EC2SecurityGroup], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Exception,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EC2.GetEC2SecurityGroupCmdlet
```

Script:

```
$Profilelist = "AwsNewProfile" 

foreach($credential in $Profilelist) {
    Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName $credential

    $regionlist = Get-AWSRegion | select -expandproperty Region
    foreach($region in $regionlist) {
        $EC2GroupList = Get-EC2SecurityGroup -Region $region | Select-Object Description, GroupId, GroupName, IpPermissions, IpPermissionsEgress, OwnerId, Tags, VpcId, @{Name='Region';expression={$region}}
    }
}
```

Comment: `$ProfileList` doesn't look like a list to me, are you sure this is doing what you want it to do and not just iterating over the letters in `AwsNewProfile`?

Comment: oh right, but how to fix this issue Get-EC2SecurityGroup : AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials ?

Comment: Does that issue persist after changing the code? If yes, please update it.

Comment: can give me of an exemple so i can update it?